# How remove purchase from in app purchase test in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hello I have done a test purchase with in app purchase flutter package, but even after refund and even after remove all cache and app, the app keep the purchase actif. I search a solution for android/playstore. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing cache of playstore.

Comment: I try to remove playstore cache but no change and I use other device I have same issue so I suspect bug about In app purchase, but I havn't this probleme with iOS

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you go into Order Management in the Play Console, find an order and click 'Refund', the confirmation page presented has a checkbox labelled '**Remove Entitlement**'. You need to select this, to remove rights to the purchase from the user in addition to refunding the user. If you do that, then the purchase will no longer be returned to the app when you query for valid purchases.

Note that from the Play Console it appears that you cannot later go back and remove the entitlement after a refund, if you didn't do it at the time of the refund.

For your own test purchases on Android, you can use the Flutter in_app_purchase API to consume the retrieved purchaseDetails via your code (**InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition.consumePurchase**) and this will remove the purchase from your purchase results, though this isn't a viable option for your cleanup of a refunded user in a release app. You would have to implement server API calls to the Google Play Android Developer API to achieve this.